# Efficient .NET pair processing

Tags: c#, arrays, list, collections, generics

The following code allows you to process all possible pairs of objects (where DoSomething(a,b) is equivalent to DoSomething(b,a) and you don't want to do both, and you never need to DoSomething(a,a)):

```
        void MyMethod (MyThing[] myArray)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < (myArray.Length-1); ++j)
            {
            for (int k = j+1; k < myArray.Length; ++k)
                {
                DoSomething(myArray[j], myArray[k]);
                }
            }
        }
```

I know this is approximately n*n/2 operations.

Is there an equally efficient way to process all possible pairs if a `List<MyThing>` is used instead of an array? (Specifically a solution where I don't have to spin over already finished elements in the inner loop). Perhaps using Enumerators somehow?

Arrays are no good because I don't know beforehand how many MyThings I will need (it could be 0, it will probably never be more than 1000). Is there a better collection for this particular usage than `List<>`? I don't need sorting, I only create new collections, clear existing collections, add to a collection, enumerate a collection, or process pairings as above. Whatever collection I use, I might need 100 to 10000 of them, so they can't be too costly to create/keep.

Lets say DoSomething() is performing collision detection & response for moving objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an equally efficient way to
>   process all possible pairs if a
>   List is used instead of an
>   array?

A `List<T>` is just a fancy wrapper around a `T[]` which resizes occasionally when exceed the capacity of your list.

You're algorithm is already optimal. If you want to use it with `List<T>`, then just change the declaration from `void MyMethod (MyThing[] myArray)` to `void MyMethod (List<MyThing> myArray)`.

> Is there a better collection for this
>   particular usage than List<>? I don't
>   need sorting, I only create new
>   collections, clear existing
>   collections, add to a collection,
>   enumerate a collection, or process
>   pairings as above. Whatever collection
>   I use, I might need 100 to 10000 of
>   them, so they can't be too costly to
>   create/keep.

First let's try to understand some things about data structures:

Internally, the `List<T>` keeps an array of size N; when you add items to the array, if you exceed the size of the internal array, then the List will allow a new array of size N*2, copy the elements over, then add your new element. The resize has a worst case of O(n); however, doubling the array on every resize means you have to add twice as many elements as before in order to trigger the worst case behavior. Lists have a property that gives them [amortized O(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) inserts, meaning you can perform n operations in O(n) time.

Usually a LinkedList will have very fast insertion. To my knowledge, it does not use an underlying array, but rather has a collection of Nodes containing Next and Previous pointers which point to adjacent items in the collection. On the plus side, worst case insert is O(1), but occasionally linked lists can have theoretically less than optimal performance as a result of poor locality of reference (i.e. adjacent items in the list are not adjacent in memory).

*I've* personally never seen a scenario where iterating over an array was perceivably slower than a linked list. Before you jump off the deep end thinking too much about locality of reference, I would definitely consider a ho-hum linked list before any other suggestion.

So with that said, if you *really* want a dynamically sized collection with good locality of reference, but also supports fast inserts, then try a [VList](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VList). It has both properties you're looking and its very easy to write:

```
public class VList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    VListNode<T> RootNode;
    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public VList() : this(4) { }

    public VList(int size)
    {
        RootNode = new VListNode<T>(4, null);
    }

    public void Add(T element)
    {
        if (RootNode.Count == RootNode.MaxSize)
            RootNode = new VListNode<T>(RootNode.MaxSize * 2, RootNode);
        RootNode.Add(element);
        Count++;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        RootNode = new VListNode<T>(4, null);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        VListNode<T> node = RootNode;
        while (node != null)
        {
            foreach (T t in node)
                yield return t;
            node = node.Next;
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class VListNode<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    readonly T[] Elements;
    public VListNode<T> Next { get; private set; }
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public int MaxSize { get; private set; }

    public VListNode(int size, VListNode<T> next)
    {
        MaxSize = size;
        Elements = new T[size];
        Next = next;
    }

    public void Add(T element)
    {
        Elements[Count] = element;
        Count++;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // iterate in reverse to return elements in LIFO order.
        for (int i = Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            yield return Elements[i];
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Simple implementation above should support Add in O(1) while maintaining good locality of reference.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this there are always opportunities to memoize the algorithm but without knowing more details about `DoSomething` it is impossible to say what could be done.

For example let's say that `DoSomething` looks like this:

```
void DoSomething(MyThing arg1, MyThing arg2)
{
    // Let's assume MyThing.Value is an int
    // and you want to print the product of both values
    Console.WriteLine(arg1.Value * arg2.Value);
}
```

In this case we could keep track of what arguments had been passed in memory and only call the method for argument combinations that we haven't seen yet.  Of course this only makes sense for a `DoSomething` implementation that takes significant execution time to warrant the memoization overhead.

Comment: each MyThing is constantly changing and therefore the pairings have to be reevaluated regularly. New MyThings might be created at any time. Does memoization still seem plausible?

Comment: @Stomp - It could, but it sounds improbable.  Honestly, the implementation of `DoSomething` is what should be driving the decision.

Comment: Lets say DoSomething() is performing collision detection & response for moving objects. (i added this to the question)

Comment: Ok, is there some way you could post the implementation?  If not can you post a reasonable facsimile?

Comment: Basically I am just questioning my use of List<> (it's easy to use) and hoping there is a better data structure that supports n*n/2 (instead of n*n) loops for pair processing...

Comment: Unfortunately not - I think what you have is about as good as it's going to get.

Comment: So there is no way to get a copy of the current enumerator (outer loop), copy it somehow, and begin processing with the next element for the inner loop?

Comment: If you want to go that route then I would suggest looking into parallelizing your code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703.aspx.

Comment: @Stomp, what's the bottleneck in your code? The time incrementing a loop counter, or the cumulative time spent inside `DoSomething`? Either you want to process each pair or you do not. The nested loops are means to that end.

Comment: @Anthony - yes, I am being evil (premature optimization). But I got curious about Enumerators and was wondering if they had some magic to start up an inner loop with the next value of the outer loop. I realize now that I asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 1):

The number of unique combinations of N items taken 2 at a time is N!/(2!(N-2)!) = N(N-1)/2 ~= O(n^2). To perform an action on every combination of two items in a list cannot be achieved with lesser complexity.

As far as the collection to use, a List will drop right in to where you had an Array, with one change; List uses a Count property to determine cardinality, as opposed to Length.

As for a more elegant way of putting As and Bs together, Linq does have some advantages:

```
var combinations = 
    from a in myThings.Reverse()
    from b in myThings.TakeWhile(x=>x!=a)
    select new {a,b};

foreach(var combo in combinations)
   DoSomething(combo.a, combo.b);
```

This is still going to be slower than your original algorithm, but I think it'll pan out a little faster than cdhowie's because it will iterate through only N extra items (to create the Reverse() enumerable), instead of skipping N(N-1) as the inner foreach of cdhowie's ends up doing.

Comment: Keith, I was trying to achieve n*n/2 for lists, ie, trying to avoid n*n. I love Linq, and thanks for the contribution!

Comment: Half of the square of a large value is still a large value. But, like I said, you can't do it any simpler. This algorithm's complexity will be about N*(N-1)/2 + N, which can be improved upon using a non-Linq solution (for loop over the indices in reverse).

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` will work just fine.  You can just replace `MyThing[]` in your method signature with `List<MyThing>`.

If you are looking for a solution that works with enumerables, just for the hell of it:

```
void MyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> myThings, Action<T, T> action)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var a in myThings)
        foreach (var b in myThings.Skip(++index))
            action(a, b);
}
```

Note that this will be a bit slower, since `Skip` will actually iterate over the skipped elements.  This may cancel out any benefits you'd get from memory caching as you approach the end of the list, and of course it's going to waste time discarding the first N elements.

Comment: was specifically trying to avoid skipping on the presumption that approximately n*n/2 skips was inefficient.

Comment: -1: Outer loop is O(n). Inner loop is O(n). `enumerable.skip(n)` is O(n), not O(1), which makes the whole thing O(n^3). This is a lot less efficient than OP's solution.

Comment: @Juliet: The OP specifically mentioned that he was interested in enumerables, so I thought I would provide an example of that code.  I clearly indicated that it will be less performant than a list-based approach.